# translation wordpress plugin using poedit

Tags: php, wordpress, poedit

I want to translate a wordpress plugin.

When in poedit catalog porperty I set path `.` or `..` then All the files which are in direct folder can be translated

But suppose some files are in folder like `payment` then how can I translate them means what path in catalog property I should set ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poedit scans directories recursively, so you’re covered.

Other than that, if you want a directory to be scanned, well, *add* it to the list of directories to scan...